# How do I use /plugins/MotionGuidePlugin.js in CreateJS 2.0.0 modules?

Tags: plugins, createjs, tween.js, tweenjs

I tried to add  plugin using the below code

```
    import { Tween, Ease } from '@createjs/tweenjs';
    import MotionGuidePlugin from '@createjs/tweenjs/src/plugins/MotionGuidePlugin';


    const tween = Tween.get(this.mySprite, { override: true, pluginData: 'MotionGuide' })
```

It's not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your motion guide data. Have you checked out the [demos in GitHub](https://github.com/CreateJS/TweenJS/blob/master/examples/MotionGuideDemo.html)?

Make sure to install the plugin once

```
createjs.MotionGuidePlugin.install(createjs.Tween);
```

Then pass motion guide data into the tween:

```
createjs.Tween.get(ball, {bounce: true, loop:3})
    .to({guide: {path: [100,100, 700,100, 800,250], orient: "fixed"}}, 2000);
```

Here are a few more demos on CodePen:

- https://codepen.io/createjs/pen/RQMXPB
- https://codepen.io/createjs/pen/4c645e6bcb0b1067074803fc364b4125

If you have specific questions, or a demo you can link to, please update your question, and I can try to answer it.

Comment: I think the version of createjs used in this sample is 1.0.
In createjs 2.0, import is available.
When using a plug-in such as MotionGuidePlugin,
import MotionGuidePlugin from '@ createjs / tweenjs / src / plugins / MotionGuidePlugin'
I think that I will describe how to use the plugin in this case.


↓ sample
import {Stage, Ticker} from '@ createjs / easeljs';

export default class CanvasMain {
   constructor () {
     ...
   }
  
}

Comment: https://github.com/createjs/easeljs/tree/2.0
npm install & import module